# JAVA Boolean variable won't change with a Switch Statement

Tags: java, oop, boolean

I'm asking the user some questions and storing the answer as boolean, true or false. At the beginning of my method, I'm declaring my variables as:

```
boolean isWindow = false;
```

then using a switch statement to assign a different value to my boolean variables:

```
        answer = INPUT.next().toUpperCase();
        switch (answer) {
        case "Y" : isWindow = true;
        case "N" : isWindow = false;
        }
```

I used a 'System.out.println' to display the value of my variable after I tried to assign it 'true' but it displays as 'false':

```
        System.out.println("Window: " + isWindow);
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: where is break keyword case "Y" : isWindow = true; break;

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings and address them.  The compiler would have warned you that you had fall-through case statements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fall through.

You forgot to break the case.

```
case "Y" : isWindow = true;break;
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

> Another point of interest is the break statement. Each break statement terminates the enclosing switch statement. Control flow continues with the first statement following the switch block. The break statements are necessary because without them, statements ***in switch blocks fall through***: All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered.

A whole new idea to avoid switch (*assuming no other cases*)

```
boolean isWindow = INPUT.next().toUpperCase().equals("Y");
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add `break` operator. Read documentation about [switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) block.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the boolean **is** changed. But after that change you immediately assign the other value to that `isWindow` boolean variable. To avoid that situation you need to put `break;` at the end of the case if you want the switch statement to leave executing next cases.

Answer (score 0):

only you need to add break for your cases.
If you didn't add the break key word it will apply all cases after the true case, stop only when finding break or the switch block end.